# How to force JPanels using GridBagLayout to resize with JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I need the components of my menuPanel to expand when the frame expands. MenuPanel is using GridBayLayout, and I've tinkered with both the fill and weight values for the panel, but nothing really seems to cause the components to resize with the frame.

I suspect something is wrong with the way I'm adding menuPanel in the display class. Furthermore, I also tried setting a layout to TanksApplication, and that didn't work either. I'm not understanding something fundamental, I think.

Main app

```
    public class TanksApplication extends JFrame{ 

       public TanksApplication(){
           super("Tanks");
       }

       public static void main (String args[]){
          Display display = new Display();
          TanksApplication frame = new TanksApplication();
          frame.add(display);
          frame.setSize(600,425);
          frame.setVisible(true);
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       }
   }
```

Display class

```
public class Display extends JPanel{    
   public Display(){
       menuPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
       GridBagConstraints con = new GridBagConstraints();

       mainMenuImageP = new JPanel();
       mainMenuImageP.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
       con.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
       con.gridy = 0;
       con.gridx = 0;
       con.gridwidth = 2;
       con.weightx = 0.5;
       con.weighty = 0.5;
       con.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
       con.ipadx = 400;
       con.ipady = 300;
       con.insets = new Insets(0,20,0,20);
       menuPanel.add(mainMenuImageP, con);

       newGameB = new JButton("New Game");
       con.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
       con.gridy = 1;
       con.gridx = 0;
       con.gridwidth = 1;
       con.weightx = 0.5;
       con.weighty = 0.5;
       con.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
       con.ipadx = 0;
       con.ipady = 0;
       con.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
       menuPanel.add(newGameB, con);

       loadGameB = new JButton("Load Game");
       con.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
       con.gridy = 1;
       con.gridx = 1;
       con.gridwidth = 1;
       con.weightx = 0.5;
       con.weighty = 0.5;
       con.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
       con.ipadx = 0;
       con.ipady = 0;
       con.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
       menuPanel.add(loadGameB, con);

       add(menuPanel);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're adding your GridBagLayout using menuPanel into the Display JPanel, the latter of which uses JPanel's default FlowLayout. FlowLayout will not resize components added to it. The solution: get **rid** of menuPanel and just use the Display JPanel. Give it a GridBagLayout and add the components to it.

so have within your Display's constructor

```
setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```

delete the `JPanel menuPanel = new JPanel();` and anywhere you have `menuPane.add(...);`, change it to simply `add(...)`;

e.g.,

```
public class Display extends JPanel{    
    public Display(){
        // !! menuPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints con = new GridBagConstraints();

        mainMenuImageP = new JPanel();
        mainMenuImageP.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        con.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        con.gridy = 0;
        con.gridx = 0;
        con.gridwidth = 2;
        con.weightx = 0.5;
        con.weighty = 0.5;
        con.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        con.ipadx = 400;
        con.ipady = 300;
        con.insets = new Insets(0,20,0,20);
        // !! menuPanel.add(mainMenuImageP, con);
        add(mainMenuImageP, con); // !!

        newGameB = new JButton("New Game");
        con.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        con.gridy = 1;
        con.gridx = 0;
        con.gridwidth = 1;
        con.weightx = 0.5;
        con.weighty = 0.5;
        con.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        con.ipadx = 0;
        con.ipady = 0;
        con.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        // !! menuPanel.add(newGameB, con);
        add(newGameB, con); // !!

        loadGameB = new JButton("Load Game");
        con.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        con.gridy = 1;
        con.gridx = 1;
        con.gridwidth = 1;
        con.weightx = 0.5;
        con.weighty = 0.5;
        con.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        con.ipadx = 0;
        con.ipady = 0;
        con.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        // !! menuPanel.add(loadGameB, con);
        add(loadGameB, con); // !!

        // !! add(menuPanel);
    }

}
```

Note that if this doesn't help, then please consider creating and posting a [minimal example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: This is a great idea, thank you. I'll give it a try. I didn't realize that Display was a panel, I'm not sure why I didn't think of it.

Comment: That was it. Thanks again.

Comment: @ulw1: you're welcome. If you absolutely need to use an inner JPanel such as menuPanel, then you would want to make your DisplayPanel use a layout that changes its components preferredSizes such as a BorderLayout.