# Size of an array becomes 0 when PaintComponent is called

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I call a method that instantiates 5 objects and adds them to an `ArrayList`. When I call another method to print the size of the `ArrayList` it shows the size is 5. When `paintComponent` is called after I create a `JPanel` and add it to a `JFrame`, and try and print the size of the `ArrayList` from `paintComponent`, it shows the size as 0. Looking at the order of `System.out.println`'s I know `paintComponent` is being called after I create and add objects to the `ArrayList`. Why does the `ArrayList` show as empty?

(This my second attempt at a short verifiable example)

Expected Output:

Size, printInfo: 5
Size, printInfo: 5
Size, paintComponent: 5
Size, paintComponent: 5

Actual Output

Size, printInfo: 5
Size, printInfo: 5
Size, paintComponent: 0
Size, paintComponent: 0

Item:

```
public class Item{
//Empty
}
```

Panel:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel extends JPanel{
    ArrayList<Item> stuff = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("Size, paintComponent: " + stuff.size());
    }

    public void setUpPanel(){
        for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
            stuff.add(new Item());
    }

    public void printInfo(){
        System.out.println("Size, printInfo: " + stuff.size());
    }
}
```

Frame:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame extends JFrame{
    public static void main (String args[]){
        Panel j = new Panel();
        j.setUpPanel();
        j.printInfo();
        Frame frame = new Frame();
        j.printInfo();
    }

    public Frame(){
        super("Test");
        add(new Panel());
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(800,600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't class your class `Frame`. There is an AWT class by that name. Make your class name more descriptive to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. In my actual program they have real names, I only did that for example purposes.

Comment: The code you post here should be real code, in the form of an `MCVE`, so we know exactly what you are doing. This has already been mentioned to you in your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40815724/pack-method-called-from-actionperformed-functions-only-sometimes and the question before that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40794576/how-to-force-jpanels-using-gridbaglayout-to-resize-with-jframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line :

```
add(new Panel());
```

adds a `Panel` that has never had its `setUpPanel()` called, so obviously its list is empty.

You probably wanted to pass your other `Panel` :

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame extends JFrame{
    public static void main (String args[]){
        Panel j = new Panel();
        j.setUpPanel();
        j.printInfo();
        Frame frame = new Frame(j);
        j.printInfo();
    }

    public Frame(Panel panel){
        super("Test");
        add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(800,600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

Note that it is not advised to use names of other existing classes, this is misleading with `java.awt.Panel` and `java.awt.Frame` for instance .

Comment: An explanation and a solution! Thanks so much. That's such a dumb mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You are working with two instances of `Panel`. The first is created in your main method:

```
public static void main (String args[]){
    Panel j = new Panel(); // <-- here
    j.setUpPanel();
    j.printInfo();
    Frame frame = new Frame();
    j.printInfo();
}
```

The second in the `Frame` constructor:

```
public Frame(){
    super("Test");
    add(new Panel()); // <-- here
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(800,600);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
```

Each of these instances holds an own instance of the list. Since you only populate one of the lists, the other still has the size 0.